# stop systemd DNS madness

Tags: networking, dns, firewall, systemd, webserver

I'm running a server on the Internet with LXC containers. Thus I need some kind of internal naming and the venerable DNSmasq has been replaced by further extensions of the devil himself (systemd)  :)

By default some how systemd-resolved listens on 0.0.0.0:53 on the Intenet!

I have and iptables rules which does NOT open 53 but some how not only does systemd bind to the Internet IP it opens the firewall too.

Any idea how to make systemd do something vaguly sane in this regard for a server that is Internet facing?

Comment: systemd-resolvd does or should not be binding to 0.0.0.0 how have you configured it and what makes you think it is listening on anything but localhost?

Comment: I havent configured it.